# Writing to a file the same way you read from it

Tags: python

The title may be a little confusing but there was no other way I could explain it. I'm first importing scores from my file, then I sort them into order, then I try to export them back to my file however in the same way it was imported - not as a list.

```
Here's a little sketch:
Import as ' James 120 ' into list [James, 120]
Export as James 120
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
  def Leaderboard(User, Score):
  Scores = open("Scores.txt", "r+")
  content = Scores.readlines()

  new = []

  for i in content:
    temp = []
    newlist = i.split(" ")
    temp.append(newlist[0])
    temp.append(int(newlist[1]))
    new.append(temp)

  temp = []
  temp.append(User)
  temp.append(Score)
  new.append(temp)

  new = sorted(new, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

  print(new)


  Scores.close()


  Leaderboard('Hannah', 3333)
```

The file currently looks like this:

```
Olly 150
Billy 290
Graham 320
James 2
Alex 333
```

Here is the end result:

```
[['Hannah', 3333], ['Alex', 333], ['Graham', 320], ['Billy', 290], ['Olly', 
150], ['James', 2]]
```

Here's what I want it exported as to my file:

```
Hannah 3333
Alex 333
Graham 320
Billy 290
Olly 150
James 2
```

Comment: Where is the code where you write to the file?

Comment: I didn't add any as there currently are not any, I tried numerous ways so it seemed useless to add them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The writing code would be something like this:

```
Scores.seek(0) # go to the beginning

for name, number in new:
    print(name, number, file=Scores)
```

Comment: Currently the working solution, if I encounter any problems I'll let you know. Cheers

Comment: I have a bit of a problem, this method works however I need to overwrite the contents of the file. When I use this it simply just adds to the file rather than removing all previous content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file.read()`, which  will read the whole file. I believe you can just run `contents = file.read()`, as  it returns as a string. There is also `file.readlines()` which returns a list of strings, each string being one line.

If this does not completely answer what you want, read more [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/cheatsheet/python-file-handling).

Comment: I just updated the post, take a look at the end as I think I was a bit unclear